# How can I enable CCD in Bullet Physics?

Tags: bullet-physics

How can I enable Continuous Collision Detection (CCD) in Bullet Physics?

Comment: The Bullet Physics SDK contains a CCD physics demo in `Demos/CcdPhysicsDemo/CcdPhysicsDemo.cpp`. Have you tried taking a look at the code to learn what they do? Engine demos exist for a reason. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable CCD per object as described in [Bullet wiki](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php?title=Anti_tunneling_by_Motion_Clamping) or [Panda3D Manual: Bullet Continuous Collision Detection](http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Bullet_Continuous_Collision_Detection). Basically you need to set `body->setCcdMotionThreshold(...);` and `body->setCcdSweptSphereRadius(0.2f);`

Comment: So if I'm shooting bullets, which are very small, this value need to be quite small, isn't this a disadvantage ?

Comment: @msell can you please elaborate what the params of this are? I have't found anything about param values in docs. Can you explain them? Thanks!